# Проблема с проброской портов в докере на виндоус

Tags: windows, docker, port, dockerfile

Я создал простой докер файл, который должен запускать мое приложение в докере.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine 
ADD project.jar project.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev","/project.jar"]
```

После этого делаю две команды,

```
 docker build -t local/java8:project .
 docker run  -p 80:80 local/java8:project
```

Вылетает такая ошибка

```
 Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint peaceful_curie (ad7ad4382ea9e4e2d17
cfd0108a536732232896faccbda3cdd05d90927ca5c83): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:80:tcp:172.17.0.3:80: input/output error.
```

Перепробовал всевозможные варианты, но ничего не помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это исправить. Добавлял секцию EXPOSE в мой файл и т.д. ничего не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла просто перезагрузка компьютера. Все команды стали работать

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте порты с номером меньше **1024**. Это требует запуска от имени **root**, что может повлечь за собой проблемы с безопасностью, даже внутри Docker-контейнера.